# Water ripples for 3D printing

Tags: modeling, mesh

How can I add a deformation to my mesh to look like ocean water ripples?
Something like this: https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/textures/natural-textures/ocean-displacement-map-6
In the example they are using a displacement map, I want to actually modify the mesh cuz I need to 3D print it

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: You can use the displace modifier if you want an image texture to drive the displacement.

Comment: You can also use the Ocean modifier

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `Ocean Modifier` [docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/physics/ocean.html). When you are done tweaking, apply the modifier and you have a real deformed mesh. With the option `Geometry > Generate` it will create a new plane, but with `Geometry > Displace` you can create the waves on the given mesh. Just be aware that in this case it needs enough resolution to work well.

[image]